# how can I get row Id or item position from recyclerview when it is clicked in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have `recyclerView_main` in my `main_activity.xml` which is holding `single_row.xml` in **Kotlin** project.

recyclerView_main is filled up with multiple rows from database.

I need to get the row ID, or position whenever I click a specific row.

is there a way to do that?

I have buttons on that row and if type `setOnClickListener()`  there is no option for `getPosition()` or `getId()`

is there a method to do this or I am missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an Adapter to handle that recyclerview? 
Inside adapter is the place where you bind each item, there you will have and onBindViewHolder function that receives position and you can set a 'setOnClickListener' there.

Here is an example code implementing a adapter:
[RecyclerView Adapter](https://github.com/RodrigoCalderano/PixelMovie/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rodrigo/pixelmovie/adapter/MoviesAdapter.kt)
Check the onBindViewHolder there

Comment: yes I am using an Adapter to handle it. So far, i figured out that `inside ViewHolder function bindItems(prd : Product) { var id = adapterPosition } ` gives me what i need. However, I need to access this `id` from `main_activity` but I dont know the way to access it now.

Comment: Just like @PhillauSofia answer, the onBindViewHolder() has an setOnClickListener  that calls an onClick function in main activity passing the object to it (you could pass the id aswell, but most likely you will prefer passing the object). Check my main activity that implements the adapter that I have posted: https://github.com/RodrigoCalderano/PixelMovie/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/rodrigo/pixelmovie/adapter/MoviesAdapter.kt

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the fact that you need to acces the id from the main_activity? When you create the adapter, you also define the onClick function that you'll use in the onBindViewHolder() method.

```
val onClick = {movie: Movie -> doSomethingWithTheId(movie.id)} 
val adapter = MoviesAdapter(movies, rowLayout, context, onClick)
```